# loop through each value in array and then use switch statement on values

Tags: php, for-loop, switch-statement

im new to php and i was wondering if anyone could help me.

i have an array, the values in the array are determined by another function, but the array will always be either warning, critical or ok, the array can be any length as well.
for example:

`$hold = array ( 'warning','warning','critical','ok');`

how do i use a switch function and the forloop function, so that it loops through every value in the array and prints out the associative message (no matter how many times it appears in the array, for example warning appears twice in the array so the it is a warning should print twice).

i have tryed the code below, however it will always print out unknown.

```
switch($hold){
  case 'ok':
  echo 'everyhting is ok';
  break;

  case 'warning':
  echo 'it is a warning';
  break;

  case 'critical':
  echo 'its critical';
  break;

  default:
  echo 'unknown';
};
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A switch statement takes quite a bit of code to write. Why not use another array to associate a message with a status in `$hold`. Like this:

```
$hold = ['warning', 'warning', 'critical', 'ok', 'this is bad'];

$messages =  ['warning'  => 'it is a warning',
              'critical' => 'its critical', 
              'ok'       => 'everyhting is ok'];

foreach ($hold as $status) {
    echo ($messages[$status] ?? 'unknown') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

As you can see, I use a [foreach () loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to go through `$hold`.

I use [an associative array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_associative.asp) and the special [Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). You can use your switch statement if you don't like this.

For a demo see: https://3v4l.org/jNkfF

Comment: hi, thank you for your code, your way does make more sense, however, my boss insists i use a switch statement, and instead of an echo it will be a specific exit.

Comment: KIKO, please endeavour to close questions where your advice is likely to already exist on Stack Overflow.  NewCoder, please ask your boss to justify limiting your code to outdated and verbose techniques.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a `switch` inside a loop, like this :

```php
foreach ($hold as $message) {
    switch ($message) {
        case 'ok':
            echo 'everyhting is ok';
        break;
        case 'warning':
            echo 'it is a warning';
        break;
        case 'critical':
            echo 'its critical';
        break;
        default:
            echo 'unknown';
    }
}
```

`foreach` seems easier to read than the classic `for`, but if you absolutely need it to be a `for`, you can write it that way instead :

```php
for ($index = 0; $index < count($hold); $index++) {
    switch ($hold[$index]) {
        // Same code as before
    }
}
```

Try this code [here](https://onlinephp.io?s=7ZFBS8NAEIXvgfyHdyikoUU8m4onwUPB3kVk3Ey7S-Ju2d0Yi_S_u5uYRtoKCh6d0zDv7bfDvMXNVm7TJE0m0tQlrkHW0g5TZC1ZrfQmm3_phFVeCapDa6osL-LDtbFMQmLaE8hh8sLO0YZzvKcJQrlW-c5xLMQS5BgRdzXOYrGQBhm_st1JH76HcgguXGB1t3q6vV8Wo_85rFAVx8xh77Ng5SOQMJh-wT1c4Ruww8HxI2rJa2pqf5bW6EqbVp-C9mmyj-fvbKPU5REurXTJbyHOywKf_QLCNNr3MeXDeDY7TSkaHnr58T-qv4nqAw%2C%2C&v=8.2.8)